# I read a question to write c programming code to find mclaurin's sum of sinx

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float sinesum(float x){
    int i, j;
    float sum = 0, fact = 1;
    for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        int y = (2*i)-1;
        for( j = 1; j <= y; j++){
            fact = (fact/j);
        }
        sum = sum + pow(-x,i+1)*fact;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main(){
    float x;
    printf("Enter the value of x in sinx function in radians: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("The value of sin(%0.2f) = %0.2f", x, sinesum(x));
}
```

1. I tried to solve the question using my knowledge
2. I checked if it is correct
3. I tried with 1.57 which is pi/2, as I know sin(pi/2) is 1, I expected the same here,
   but I got 1.83 as my output
4. I humbly request you to explain why this is happening

Comment: But, even then I'm getting a different answer i.e., 1.87!

Comment: what's wrong with my powers

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but: as a general rule (unless you have special requirements), always use `double`, not `float`.

Comment: Before asking on Stack Overflow, you should have monitored execution of your program, using a debugger or `printf` statements placed throughout the code. Watching what values were used for `fact` in each iteration and showing the values of `pow(-x,i+1)` and comparing those values to hand-calculations of the series would have revealed the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your routine:

- `fact` must be initialized to 1 when starting to compute it, *i.e.*, inside the loop on `i`, before the loop on `j` that computes `fact`. (Or, instead of computing `fact` from scratch each time, just continue computing it from the value in the previous iteration on `i`.)
- The power of `x` should be `y` (which is `2*i-1`), not `i+1`.
- Because that power is always odd, it cannot be used to cause alternating signs in the terms. You should compute `pow(x, y)` (or otherwise compute `x` to the power of `y`) and add some other code to alternate addition and subtraction.

Comment: Even if I've initialized that as you said in your first statement, I'm not getting any correct answer, rather getting larger than what I am getting with the code I've written.       Getting to the second point you've mentioned, for the first term, it is i+1=2 then for the second, i+1=3 and so on. So, nothing a major change here even if I change according to your point.

Comment: @KonduruPremsai: The powers of x should not be 2 for the second, 3 for the third, and so on. They should be 1 for the first term, 3 for the second, 5 for the third, and generally `2*i+1` for term `i`. On my own system, I made changes to fix the errors described in this answer, and the resulting program prints correct results.